# Button Drop Down Menu items activate parent instead

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, parent-child, submenu

I have a drop down menu off of a button:hover but when I click the child links it acts as though I am clicking the button that is the parent (the button that the hover is set to).

Html:

```
 <button id="Portfoliobut" class="dropbtn" onclick="window.location.href='index.html#Portfolio'" data-toggle="dropdown">Portfolio<div class="dropdown-content">
                  <a id="dropitlow" class="weblink1" >Web / UI</a>
                  <a id="dropitlow" class="designlink1">Design</a>
                  <a id="dropitlow" class="marketinglink1">Marketing</a>
                  <a id="dropitlow" class="otherlink1">Other</a>
</div></button>
```

Jquery:

```
 <script>

 $("#homebut").click(
function(){ window.location = "index.html" } 
 );
       $(".weblink1").click(
function(){ window.location = "web.html" } 
 );
       $(".designlink1").click(
function(){ window.location = "design.html" } 
 );
     $(".marketinglink1").click(
function(){ window.location = "marketing.html" } 
 );
      $(".otherlink1").click(
function(){ window.location = "other.html" } 
 );
```

CSS:

```
 #dropitlow{
z-index: 10;
height: 8px;
background-color: burlywood;

  }
 #dropitlow:hover{
background-color: honeydew;
z-index: 10;
```

}

```
 #Portfoliobut{
width: 33.3%;
height: 100%;
background-color: aliceblue;
float: left;

 }
 .dropdown-content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
font-size: 10pt;
width: 100%;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
z-index: 8


   }

   .dropbtn {
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
```

}

I am not sure how to make the anchors change window location to what I have set up in jquery. As is I click on the sub menu items and the parent (button) highlights as the whole menu being part of the clickable button. I would like to keep it a button as it is styled along side other menu buttons.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, `div` and `a` can't be a child of `button`

Comment: damn, thank you i will change it